# How to tell if a website is using shared hosting or just masking IP address?

Tags: networking, dns, dynamic-dns, shared-hosting, reverse-dns

When I do a reverse lookup on a certain website, it returns a Dyn IP as below:

```
C:\Users>nslookup xyz.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    xyz.com
Addresses:  216.146.46.11
      216.146.46.10
```

The IP is owned by Dynamic Network Services, Inc. (a.k.a Dyn). When I did a reverse IP domain check, I happened to find 500+ other websites hosted on same IP. Is this because of shared hosting or is it just hiding the real IP like how Cloudfare does?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to tell with absolute certainty, unless you have access to complete traffic logs from the ISP of that address (then just see if every inbound request is followed by an outbound request). There are, however, a few things that may give you a hint.

First, I suggest digging in to the owner of the IP(s) you get, and see what services they offer. If they offer both dos/obfuscation and "simple hosting" or "static-only web hosting" then you're out of luck. Keep in mind it may be both dos protection and multi-site hosting rolled up in one.

Second, let's not forget the point of multi-site hosting on a single ip: saving money. IPs are expensive, so stacking multiple hosts on a single ip saves money. Most hosting services that sell stacked hosts like that are rather small time, or only do so for static-only sites (like s3 on aws); such services fit nicely into both categories since the true file location is probably in another datacenter(s) entirely.

After you've stacked up 10 hosts on one ip to save money, it makes no sense to then turn around and give each of these sites space on each of 10 other IPs. Therefor, if there are multiple ip addresses returned from dns, it is probably something like cloudflare, which is designed as high-availability as much as dos protection. Also try querying the same name from/through some different dns zones or servers. The more different IPs you get the more likely it is a larger service like cloudflare, not so likely a cost-saving host-stack.

Comment: I did dig into the owner of the IP. While Dyn does provide managed DNS service, DDoS mitigation, domain registration etc., no where does it say that it provides web hosting.This is the confusing part. The DNS servers used by the domain are again the Dyn DNS servers. I am almost certain from the looks of it that this is a service like Cloudfare, but wondering why the hosting IP is that of Dyn.

Comment: Dynamic dns is a common defense for dos attacks. If one ip gets dos'ed, just use another one. The admins will then contact the admins of the blacklister to get the dos'ed ip un-blacklisted, making it viable once again. Dynamic dns is just a faster way to handle rerouting.
Also, some domain services do martial hosting, which is sort-of half way between hosting and dns. The dns address resolves to one of their IPs, which responds with a simple html page that has a frame to your real ip. I've seen this used to redirect dns to a dynamic provider, and even to private isps. All makes sense to me.

Comment: Do you have links or references to martial hosting? I have never heard of this before. Maybe I could read about it.

Comment: 8Sorry, martial is a typo. "Partial hosting" is what I meant, and just because I didn't know what else to call it. I used to use it with godaddy to redirect the domain name to a dynamic dns name (ddns.com via noip.com) on port 8080 (80 is blocked by isp) to my home router, which forwarded the port to a raspberry pi. Here's a link on godaddy to setup the hosting (they call it masked forwarding): https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forward-or-mask-your-domain-or-subdomain-422